# PDF file is not getting opened in new tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to open PDF file in new tab, but it is getting opened in the same tab. I have gone through so many questions, but none of them work.

It looks like there is some problem with fuction in openInNewTab().

Below is the aspx code:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attachment Name" SortExpression="Attachment_Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAttachmentName" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="View" CssClass="noline clsAttachmentName" Text='<%#Bind("Attachment_Name") %>' OnClientClick="openInNewTab();"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

openInNewTab() function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function openInNewTab() { 
        window.document.forms[0].target = '_blank';
        setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = ''; }, 0);
        return true;
    }
    </script>
```

vb code:

```
    Protected Sub gvAttachment_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvAttachment.RowCommand
        Try
            If (e.CommandName = "View") Then
                Dim AttachmentID As Integer
                Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
                AttachmentID = CInt(gvAttachment.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
                ViewState("AttachmentID") = AttachmentID
                LoadAttachment(AttachmentID)
                ModData.WriteViewLog(User_ID, "General Attachments", AttachmentID, "General Attachments", "View", Session.Item("SoftID"), 0)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Components.ExceptionLogger.HandleException(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub LoadAttachment(ByVal AttachmentID As Integer)
            Try
                Dim FiletoDownload As String
                Dim MyFileInfo As FileInfo
                Dim FileSize As Long
                Dim strpath As String
                strpath = String.Empty
                objBL_PatientEdu = New BL_PatientEducation(Session.Item("SoftId"))
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                dt = objBL_PatientEdu.viewAttachmentByID(AttachmentID)
                If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    strpath = dt.Rows(0)("Attachment_Location").ToString() 
                End If
                If File.Exists(strpath) Then
                    FiletoDownload = strpath
                    MyFileInfo = New FileInfo(FiletoDownload)
                    FileSize = MyFileInfo.Length
                    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(strpath)
                    Response.Clear()
                    Response.ClearContent()
                    Response.ClearHeaders()
                    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=""" & filename & """")
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", FileSize.ToString())
                    Response.Buffer = True
                    Response.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strpath))
                    Response.End()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Components.ExceptionLogger.HandleException(ex)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot control if a pdf is openend in a new tab, that is up to the user and their browser settings.

Comment: window.document.forms[0].target = '_blank';
        setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = ''; }, 0);  
 target should only be '_blank'  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a it looks like you set it right, but then set it to the current window instead...

Comment: @ThisGuy If I comment setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = ''; }, 0); then pdf is being opened in new tab, However now all other calls like Response.Redirect also is getting opened in a new tab, which is I don't want.

Comment: OK, I suggest you study and write down your workflow. try to understand what items need to be in new tab ( you now can do that consistently ) and which need to open in current tab ( or however else you want to do it ) . try to understand what the conditions for each of those behaviors is.  you can create another function: say, openInCurrentTab()....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line

```
setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = ''; }, 0);
```

to this

```
setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = ''; }, 1);
```

and now it is working fine.